# how to search and display youtube videos in uitableview?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, search, youtube-api

Im looking for a simple example that shows how to search for a video,
and display the results in a uitableview.

I've been trying to do this, without any luck.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Youtube API.

Here is what you need to do:

1. get JSON from Youtube API.
2. Use JSONSerialization and then get the name, title, thumbnail and ID for the Video.
3. Populate UITableView with the data.

Comment: Can you provide me a link of youtube search API.